# Creating a random color inside object HowlerJS

Tags: javascript, random, colors, howler.js

So right now I am trying to make a patatap clone.  I want to make it to where everytime I press a key the a circle is scaled down by 10% in a random position on the screen with a random color.  So far I got everything but the random color part down.  So how to change this to a randomly generated color everytime?

```js
var keyData = {
  q: {
    sound: new Howl({
      src: ['sounds/bubbles.mp3']
    }),
    color: '#1abc9c'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, another workaround for this would be to generate colors with a randomized `RGB` value rather than `hex` index as this would probably be easier to calculate.

Here's an example of a randomized `RGB` color value function in a personal project:

```
function randomColor() {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

So on your `howl` function, call the `randomColor` function as your new color.

Answer (score 1):

Change src: `['sounds/bubbles.mp3']` to urls: `['sounds/bubbles.mp3']`

as for creating a random color your best bet is to create an empty array like so:

`var arr = []`

Afterwards, create a function that would generate random numbers into an array like so:

```
function generateRandomColors(num){
//make an array
var arr = []
//repeat num times
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
    //get random color and push into arr
    arr.push(randomColor())
}
//return that array
return arr;
}
```

Then to generate the random numbers themselves create a function similar to this:

```
function pickColor(){
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
return colors[random];
}
```